# Why are files uploaded through createUploadUrl() filling up my datastore and blobstore and how do I delete them?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a PHP application on Google App Engine that recently maxed out the free quota of 1GB in Datastore Stored Data. I was not even aware that PHP on GAE could even use the datastore. Turns out that any file that is uploaded via CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl() creates entries in the datastore under **BlobInfo**

```
SELECT * FROM __BlobInfo__
```

The Blob Viewer also lists all of the files uploaded through createUploadUrl(). It looks like these files are unnecessary as I can manually upload a file to my bucket and still create an image serving url with CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl() without creating any entries to these tables.

My question is how do I delete them? Shouldn't they be deleted after they are put into my bucket? or I call move_uploaded_file()?? I am doing everything as per the docs.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Even files uploaded through [Google's Wordpress for GAE](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) are in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete these datastore entries using the admin console. I think you'd need to upload a lot (I mean a lot) of blobs before you come close to any quotas.

The blob keys are created and recorded against the app because the upload mechanism also supports apps that were written for the legacy upload mechanism that wrote to blobstore rather than cloud storage.

Comment: I have uploaded about 50,000 files which is taking up about 0.96 GBytes of data in my datastore. To delete these files through the admin console 30 at a time will take too long. I could write a script but PHP has no access to the BlobStore?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk